# Visual studio online for onpremise applications

Tags: powershell, ssl, azure-devops

I am trying to implement automated testing with visual studio online for application which located on physical server in my domain. Documentation says to use ssl certificate or add host to trusted hosts. Both options does not help if I do it on target server.

So it it possibe to run test agent setup task (or file copy task or run functional test task) from visual studio online to onpremise physical server ?

Similar tasks, but with azure virtual machines works fine.

Comment: What error did you get when work with physical server? Does the physical server can be accessed from internet via the host name or IP address?

Comment: In case using http: System.ArgumentException: Unable to resolve path $env:SystemDrive\TestAgent. Connecting to remote server 62.216.52.66 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

Comment: Physical server can be accessed from internet via IP, from powershell

Comment: Using SSL:  The server certificate on the destination computer (62.216.52.66:5986) has the following errors:The SSL certificate could not be checked for revocation. The server used to check for revocation might be unreachable.

Comment: How did you add host to trusted hosts?

Comment: I just add * all hosts to trusted, as it is only option I have with visual studio online

Comment: Try the setup with this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: I've tried this setup previously, but now I've noticed, that command Test-WsMan COMPUTER passes successfully if I add it as powershell comand in build workflow. But still no luck to pass mentioned biuld steps.

Comment: Did you restart the winrm service after add trusted hosts?

Comment: Yes, I did a few times

Comment: What build agent are you using? Hosted or your own?

Comment: It is a hosted agent

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, and the settings should mostly the same as the virtual machines in Azure. Refer to this link for details: [Set up environments to run automated test tasks with your build tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Test/automated-tests/set-up-automated-test-environments-builds)